# Python Pandas File Parsing: Another matrix dimension for "\n\n" delimiter

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, parsing

In my text files, every "\n\n" row seperates different simulation results, and I need them seperated.

Is there a way to add another dimension to the matrix table in pandas? Or to pull numpy arrays in sections of every N rows (8 in my case)?

Panda reading the data in:

```
    xPos    yPos    range    otherData ...
 0 -800.0   711.2    6100     73.56
 1 -700.0   751.2    6100     73.56
 2 -600.0   701.2    6100     73.56
 3 -500.0   741.2    6100     73.56
 4 -400.0   700.2    6100     73.56
 5 -300.0   677.2    6100     73.56
 6 -200.0   789.2    6100     73.56
 7 -100.0   200.2    6100     73.56
                                    # pandas cobines \n\n sections
 8 -800.0   711.2    6100     73.56
 9 -700.0   751.2    6100     73.56
10 -600.0   701.2    6100     73.56
11 -500.0   741.2    6100     73.56
12 -400.0    97.0    6100     73.56
13 -300.0   677.2    6100     73.56
14 -200.0   789.2    6100     73.56
15 -100.0   200.2    6100     73.56

16 -800.0   711.2    6100     73.56
17 -700.0   751.2    6100     73.56
18 -600.0   701.2    6100     73.56
19 -500.0   741.2    6100     73.56
20 -400.0   700.2    6100     73.56
21 -300.0   677.2    6100     73.56
22 -200.0   789.2    6100     73.56
23 -100.0   200.2    6100     73.56
```

If there is no easy read solution to what I am asking, then I what is the easiest way to make matrix arrays of each section? I need the easy access of `pd_data['xPos']` for each simulation.

I would like to access data like:

```
# [sim run #] [row] [col]
print(simRun[1][4][1])     # prints 97.0 in the example above

run2 = 1
print(simRun[run2][len(run2)-1]['yPos'] # prints 200.2 in the example above
```

Keep in mind, these text files can be huge with thousands of simulation results.

---

Tyler, your code works well, but... (so close!)

Here is the old "brute force" way I was doing it:

```
fd = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1],sep='\s{2,}',comment='#',engine='python')
nSim = int(len(fd)/8)
xRange = []
for x in range(nSim):
    xRange.append(fd['xPos'][x*8])
print(xRange) # This works for the time being.
xPlot = np.array(xRange)
```

The purpose is to grab the starting x & y positions in each individual simulation runs so I can use it for plotting and other analysis. The first row of the chunks are the initial starting positions of each sim.

Here is how I applied your code:

```
sims = []
cSize = 9 # I had to go bigger than every 8 here to account for "\n\n"
for chunk in pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1],sep='\s{2,0}',comment='#',engine='python',chunksize=cSize):
    sims.append(chunk)
for s in range(len(sims)):
    print(sims[s]['xPos'][7]) # This results in error.
print(sims[0]['xPos'][7]) # This works fine.
```

The code seems to work just fine giving each chunk in the list with it's own header. However, being able to grab the last row of x position (col) in all the chunks isn't working.

I appreciate any feedback on how to make the bottom code work. The text files are full of columns of data, and accessing them via header name would make my day easier.

Comment: do you read this data in from somewhere? If so, you could just split that file on `\n\n` and create separate dataframes

Comment: It is read from a .txt file. There are multiple files to process, each .txt file is a different "profile/scenario" filled with grid(x & y) simulations.

Answer (score 0):

If you know beforehand how big the partitions are you can read them in chunk by chunk. (chunk size 8 in your example data.) I also assume you are reading in a csv file.

```
chunksize = 8
for chunk in pd.read_csv('file_name1.csv', chunksize=chunksize):
    print(chunk)
```

or create a new dataframe with sector labels:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
chunksize = 8
for counter, chunk in enumerate(pd.read_csv('file_name1.csv', chunksize=chunksize)):
    chunk['sector'] = counter
    df = df.append(chunk)
```

Comment: Thanks, Tyler. I will try this out and let you know how it goes.